# Can I know how to apply the function of connecting to DApp such as Uniswap when installing Metamask?

Tags: metamask, dapps, uniswap

If you press the Connecting button on a site such as Uniswap, the ability to connect the metamask is activated.We also want to apply such a function to our homepage.

I knew as below. Is this the right way?

---

Based on the information here, the logos are stored off-chain in their centralized database.

However you can add in a token via wallet_watchAsset.

Sample code:

```js
const tokenAddress = '0xd00981105e61274c8a5cd5a88fe7e037d935b513';
const tokenSymbol = 'TUT';
const tokenDecimals = 18;
const tokenImage = 'http://placekitten.com/200/300';

try {
  // wasAdded is a boolean. Like any RPC method, an error may be thrown.
  const wasAdded = await ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_watchAsset',
    params: {
      type: 'ERC20', // Initially only supports ERC20, but eventually more!
      options: {
        address: tokenAddress, // The address that the token is at.
        symbol: tokenSymbol, // A ticker symbol or shorthand, up to 5 chars.
        decimals: tokenDecimals, // The number of decimals in the token
        image: tokenImage, // A string url of the token logo
      },
    },
  });

  if (wasAdded) {
    console.log('Thanks for your interest!');
  } else {
    console.log('Your loss!');
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted has nothing to do with wallet connect. You should do something like this:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const ethEnabled = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This will enable your page to connect to user's wallet and you can use this to interact with blockchain.